# How to read the PID of the previous executed process in C?

Tags: c, process, pid, context-switch

I would like to read the PID of the previous executed process in C.

For example, I have process 1 which sleeps for 1s and when wakes up reads the PID of the process executing before the context switch. Process 1 runs with higher priority than the other processes so as when the sleep time finishes it immediately scheduled to run.

How can I get the information on which process PID run before its execution was interrupted so as process 1 executes?

Comment: out of curiosity - what for?

Comment: i am experimenting to see how th CFS works etc. I try to load a lot of processes to reach the limit of the processes able to execute in the target latency of the system. Process 1 should run very fast ie high priority and sleep time 1ms. I am interesting to see which process executed before and which it will run after.

Comment: If this is possible at all, it will be highly dependent on the OS you are using.  When you have only the [tag:c] tag, people assume you are asking only about ISO C, which contains nothing remotely like this - it describes no concept of "scheduler" or "process".  So please be more specific.

Comment: I would be kind of skeptical that any OS supports this, except maybe through some sort of kernel debugging functionality.  This sort of fine detail is considered to be none of a program's business, and could possibly even help with side-channel attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to read the PID of the previous executed process in C.

How can one determine which process was executed before or after, more on in a multiprocessor architecture in which several threads (even in the same process) can be executing `fork()` at the same time?

> For example, I have process 1 which sleeps for 1s and when wakes up reads the PID of the process executing before the context switch.

how can it get the pid of the process that was executing before that context switch?  In a context switch the process deciding the next process to execute doesn't tell the next process to execute which was the last.  Even when a context switch happens by means of a hardware interrupt in which the process is not making a sleep()/wait()/pause() system call.  System calls return information on how the system call went, but there's no place to store what process lead to a context switch and provide the number of the process id (indeed, it should be the thread id, as a process can have several threads and not only one)

> Process 1 runs with higher priority than the other processes so as when the sleep time finishes it immediately scheduled to run.

Why do you assume process 1 runs at higher priority if the scheduler assigns priorities dynamically when considering which process to run next?

> How can I get the information on which process PID run before its execution was interrupted so as process 1 executes?

You cannot.  It's impossible as the context switch can happen because a hardware interrupt, when your process is not capable of storing it anywhere.  Even signal handlers run in user mode, so there's no way in which you can have access to the last executed process. More because in a multiprocessor computer the kernel can be handling several context switches **at the same time**.

Indeed, telling a user process the pid of the process that was run last, could represent a security breach, as not all the processes belong to the same user.  Remember today systems are not only multithread/multiprocess/multiprocessor, but **also multiuser.**